# C# преобразование строки к числу в разных системах счисления (аналог формата %i scanf в C[++])

Tags: c#, c, системы-счисления, преобразование-типов, scanf

Думаю, многим известно, что формат `%i` функции `scanf()` (и её разновидностей) может преобразовывать к числу три разных формата записи чисел:

- Восьмеричная запись: '0' + цифры 0..7
- Десятичная запись: любые цифры 0..9
- Шестнадцатиричная запись: '0x' + цифры 0..9 и буквы A..F

Поэтому данный код на C/C++ выполняется:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
    int o, d, h;
    char*str = "0101 101 0x101";
    sscanf(str, "%i %i %i", &o, &d, &h);
    printf("%i %i %i", o, d, h);
    return 0;
}
// output: 65 101 257
```

Как добиться такого же поведения в C#? Методы `int.Parse()` и `Convert.ToInt32()` не работают таким же образом:

```
> var str = "0101 101 0x101";
> str.Split().Select(s => int.TryParse(s, out int x) ? x : -1).ToArray()
int[3] { 101, 101, -1 }
> str.Split().Select(s =>
. {
.     try { return Convert.ToInt32(s); }
.     catch { return -1; }
. }).ToArray()
int[3] { 101, 101, -1 }
```

Хотя данные методы имеют перегрузки с указание числового формата, он всё равно работает иным образом:

```
> int.Parse("0xFF", NumberStyles.HexNumber)
System.FormatException: Входная строка имела неверный формат.
```

В данном случае лишнее вхождение строки "0x". Без него работает:

```
> int.Parse("101", NumberStyles.HexNumber)
257
```

Но остаётся проблема с числами в восьмеричной записи, так как согласно спецификации перечисления [`NumberStyles`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.globalization.numberstyles?view=netcore-3.1), он не содержит формата для данной записи.

Как быть в данной ситуации, если нужен метод, который одновременно может преобразовывать числа разных форматов систем счисления?

Comment: @AlexF, да, работает, я даже ответ с этим добавил. Проблема в поиске полного аналога, который не требует дописывания какого-либо кода.

Answer (score 0):

Видимо, единственным решением будет написание своего "костыля":

```
> int MyParse(string str)
. {
.     int @base = 10;
.     str = str.Trim();
.     if (str.Length > 2 && str.StartsWith("0x"))
.         (str, @base) = (str.Substring(2), 16);
.     else if (str.Length > 1 && str.StartsWith("0"))
.         (str, @base) = (str.Substring(1), 8);
.     return Convert.ToInt32(str, @base);
. }
> var str = "0101 101 0x101";
. str.Split().Select(MyParse).ToArray()
int[3] { 65, 101, 257 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Если нужно именно с "0x", то откажитесь от int.(Try)Parse.
Используйте Converter.ToInt32:

```
var res = Convert.ToInt32("0xFF", 16);
Console.WriteLine(res); //255
```